# Get area of figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I get my python script, from users data_set I should draw curves, next find intersection point, draw straight line via her and find area of 2 figures. How to do that if I don't know function of that figures?

[image]

On this example 2 figures, left and right of my line, how to found their area

Comment: Assuming a Gaussian distribution: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/normal_distribution/areas_normal.html

Comment: I had show just example, yes, on picture normal, but in real situation it be various. Or you mean I should normilize my curves and next use your rule?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a simple approximation of the area under a curve by summing the discrete y values and multiplying by the x interval.  If you show the code you used to create the figure, maybe we could suggest how to do that.  See [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) for an introduction to numerical integration.

Comment: Figure generate from data_set, its randomly, right answer is to normilize data, thats all